# com.maverick.ssh.SshException: EOF received from remote side [Unknown cause]

Tags: exception, authentication, ssh, aix, eof

When I tried to log in AIX server, through a java code/application, I am getting the below exception,

```
    INFO: J2SSH:KEY_EXCHANGE_FAILURE
    com.maverick.ssh.SshException: EOF received from remote side [Unknown cause]
        at com.maverick.ssh2.TransportProtocol.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.maverick.ssh2.TransportProtocol.j(Unknown Source)
        at com.maverick.ssh2.TransportProtocol.nextMessage(Unknown Source)
        at com.maverick.ssh.components.jce.DiffieHellmanGroup1Sha1.performClientExchange(Unknown Source)
        at com.maverick.ssh2.TransportProtocol.e(Unknown Source)
        at com.maverick.ssh2.TransportProtocol.processMessage(Unknown Source)
        at com.maverick.ssh2.TransportProtocol.startTransportProtocol(Unknown Source)
        at com.maverick.ssh2.Ssh2Client.connect(Unknown Source)
        at com.maverick.ssh.SshConnector.connect(Unknown Source)
        at com.maverick.ssh.SshConnector.connect(Unknown Source)
```

Server details :

- Server type : **AIX**
- Mode of connection : **SSH**
- Authentication : **password based authentication. Not key based.**

I surfed in internet, but not able get clear answer for this issue. Please some one help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The java code in question is using the J2SSH Maverick API from [SSHTOOLS Limited](http://www.sshtools.com) and is throwing the exception during key exchange. This specific error means the remote server disconnected whilst key exchange was being performed.

There are many potential reasons for this. It's likely that the server did not like something in the key exchange messages and disconnected or even seg-faulted. The resolution would be to ensure your using the latest version of the API above and if it continues to be a problem contact the company for support.